# Folder structures eclipse spring MVC - uploading Images

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller, gradlew

I am creating uploading files application in Spring MVC application. I am using thymeleaf templates. And there's problem because i Have folder structure builded by gradle(STS).
I have such line in controller:

```
imageDir=new File("C:/Users/lukas/workspace/uploadingFiles/src/main/resources/images");
```

The problem occurs here in thymeleaf showimage html script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head>
<title>Script shows specified image</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/styles.css" 
th:href="@{/css/styles.css}"/>
</head>
<body>
<div class="center">
    <h2><a th:href="@{/uploaded}">Click here to previous page where you can choose image to show</a></h2>
</div> 
    <img th:src="@{${path}}"/>

<div class="center2">
    <p th:text="${path}">dddd</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

It doesn't display \images\0.jpg properly. Only one picture is displayed from other folders not exactly how specified in above line path. It gives output from other other folders for ex.: static images. Even in folder are other images the shown is only one. Even it image isn't in specified in the path.

Comment: So where? from hard drive I couldnt access content from thymeleaf